# MySQL Search and replace some text with other column value

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL query and I wanted to insert the value of my **bbcode_uid** column into the replace statement

```
UPDATE `phpbb_posts` 
   SET `post_text` = REPLACE(post_text, '&quot;]', '&quot;:*MY_BBCODE_UID*]')
```

is this possible?

Comment: Yes. It is absolutrely correct. Go ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I used

```
UPDATE `phpbb_posts`
   SET `post_text` = REPLACE(post_text, '&quot;]', CONCAT('&quot;:', bbcode_uid, ']'))
```

if there's better syntax, i'm interested